# Character assignment from a shuffled array

Tags: android, arraylist, random

(edited, hopefully more clear)
I'm learning to code for Android and would like to make a program that will randomly select a single number from a range, then run a random select of the remaining numbers for specified iterations.

> 4 iterations in this example:

- 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10, randomly select an integer from the set, say "7", then another new set,
- 1 2 3 4 5 6 8 9 10, randomized, then select an integer from the new set, say "2", then a new set,
- 1 3 4 5 6 8 9 10, randomly select an integer from the new set, say "9", then a new set,
- 1 3 4 5 6 8 10, randomly select an integer, say "6".

> Output would be 2, 6, 7, 9.

Would i be using character assignment, a=1, b=2 ect, from a shuffled array? I want the first random selected number to not be present in the consecutive sets to be randomized. Where, finally, 7,2 and 9, in this example, are not in the last set. The focus is not on avoiding duplication but generating a new specific non-sequential set to randomly choose another unique number from.

Comment: Keep it simple.  Use a List and as members are selected, you remove them from the list.  From there you select another random member of your list and you're guaranteed to never pick the same number twice (unless there are duplicates).  Not sure what you mean by char assignment.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the following example:

```java
public static void main(String args[]) {
    // Create our test case
    List<Integer> integerList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
        integerList.add(i+1);
    }

    // Print out 4 randomly chosen elements from list   
    Random rand = new Random();
    for(int i=0; i<4; i++) {
        System.out.println(selectOne(rand, integerList));
    }
}

private static Integer selectOne(Random rand, List<Integer> integerList) {
    int randomIndex = rand.nextInt(integerList.size());
    return integerList.remove(randomIndex);
}
```

To each successive call to selectOne, a random element is removed and returned.  Since you cannot remove the same item twice, for each element in the list, it will be selected exactly once.  This works for a series of numbers as well as a deck of cards.

In fact, if you use the following, then you could use a `List<Integer>` as easily as a `List<Card>` :

```
private static <T> T selectOne(Random rand, List<T> integerList) {
    int randomIndex = rand.nextInt(integerList.size());
    return integerList.remove(randomIndex);
}
```

Comment: "a random element is removed and returned", is not what i'm looking for. Removal of the selected integer from the range and a new set generated where the rest of the range remain.

Comment: Removal of the selected integer from the previous range and a new set generated where the rest of the range remains, then randomly selected from for a new unique number.         An array list of indexed objects seems to be what i need to be doing.

Comment: @AjaxBlackburn Why would you generate a new set?  If you want the possibility to reselect the same, then you don't remove it from the list.  In fact unless you're dealing with a dynamic list, you could simply generate a number from 1 to 10 and get the same effect.

Comment: the new set would specifically have 1 ~ 10 minus the last random pick. I want the last random pick to be "set aside" and a new random pick from the remainder. if i could figure out how to do that once I might be able to iterate the rest with a dynamic shrinking specified set. 1 3 4 5 6 8 9 10, then 1 3 4 5 6 8 10. I don't want to select from the same set of sequential numbers. example: **mylist.remove**(index item to be removed, but i want the random pick in this parenthetical).

Comment: @AjaxBlackburn You'll have to forgive me because I still don't understand.  In your example, you wanted to pick from a set of numbers that you haven't picked from yet.  That's what my answer provides.  It seems that you mean to simply pick another member of the list that isn't the same as the last, but your example doesn't seem to indicate that.

Comment: the trouble is all on me. I have miss read "returned" as 'return the random pick to the 1 ~ 10 set.' Then a new random pick is removed and returned back into the list available to be picked again in successive runs through the program. Not the case. My ignorance.

Comment: @AjaxBlackburn No problem.  Glad you're back on track.  :)